# who is Goddess TArA

Tags: shakti, kali, tara

Who is Goddess TArA.

Though I heard about HER as one of the Dasa mahavidyas, whats the significance of HER moolamantra and dhyana and upasana as far as our materialistic life is concerned.

Also,I read from @Rickross, that she is holding a skull-cup ( is it naarakapaala or kapaalapatra ?) in one of her 4 hands.

In Buddhist Tantra(pls correct me, this word buddhist tantra), there's Goddess Green colored Goddess called Green Tara having wearing snakes as ornaments!

Are these Ugra-Tara & Green Tara same?

Answer (score 1):

No they are not technically the same.

Buddhist tantra  is a sect like vajrayAna and they have deities which are worshiped this way. Includes yoginis and dakinis etc

With respect to tArA. There are many variations in buddhism like

White tArA
Green tArA 
And so on.

Some ritualistic aspects may overlap between Hinduism and buddhism.

Each tara has different significance in buddhism.

Comment: Please elaborate on Goddess Tara from DasaMahavidyas..

Comment: @SaMolPP we already have some threads on goddess tArA. Did you go thru them?

Answer (score 0):

In tantric buddhism there are 21 forms of tara,all have different colors and gestures.Their leader is green tara also known as arya-tara.She belongs to amoghasiddhi buddha family.
Hindu worship the ekajati tara,who belongs to akshobhya buddha family.
Kurukulla is also a tara same as Janguli,Mahasri,Marici etc.
All tara cult mainly originated within Mahayana-mantrayana buddhism.
Ekajati tara has a special from called mahacina tara,her origin is in mahacina or tibbet.
Ugra tara,ekajati,mahacina,nilasarasvati are many names of same goddess.